# For prime $p$, normal subgroups of $SL(2, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ remains normal in $GL(2, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, normal-subgroups

Let $p$ be a prime. If $G$ is a normal subgroup of $SL(2, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ , then is $G$ also normal in $GL(2, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p\ge5$, $SL(2,p)/\{\pm I\}$ is simple, so the only nontrivial
normal subgroup of $SL(2,p)$ is $\{\pm I\}$ which is normal in $GL(2,p)$.
You'll then have to treat the cases $p=2$ and $p=3$ separately.

Comment: Why is $SL(2,p)/\{I,-I\}$ simple ?

Comment: ??? @misao $SL(2,p)$ is not simple.

Comment: I meant to say the quotient ...

Comment: @misao It's $PSL(2,p)$, a well-known example of a simple group of classical Lie type. See textbooks on group theory.

Comment: Can my claim be extended for $\mathbb Z/n$, where $n$ is a product of two distinct primes or a power of prime ?

Comment: Shark  the unknown, sir can we replace $2$ by general integer $n$?

Answer (score -1):

Note the matrix (with $a\neq 0$)
$$m_a=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
a &0\\
0 &1
\end{array}}\right]$$
has determinant $a$ and inverse 
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
a^{-1} &0\\
0 &1
\end{array}}\right]$$
in $GL(2, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$. Therefore every matrix $g\in GL(2, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ can be written as $m_as$ (where $a=\det g$) for some $s\in SL(2, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$.

Now for all $s\in SL$, $sGs^{-1}=G$. Then for any $g\in GL$, let $g=m_as$, so $gGg^{-1}=m_asGs^{-1}m_a^{-1}=m_aGm_a^{-1}=G$ (somehow)

Can someone help me complete this proof :(