# For which $n$ , does normal subgroups of $SL(2, \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)$ remain normal in $GL(2, \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

Let $n$ be either a product of two distinct primes or a power of a prime. Then is it true that normal subgroups of $SL(2, \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)$ remains normal in $GL(2, \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$ ?

The $n$=prime case was dealt with here [For prime $p$, normal subgroups of $SL(2, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ remains normal in $GL(2, \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635234/for-prime-p-normal-subgroups-of-sl2-mathbb-z-p-mathbb-z-remains-normal)

Comment: I suspect you want to show that $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is a *characteristic* subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ from which your question will follow, but I can't think how to prove it (or even if it's true generally).

Comment: This is certainly true in arbitrary dimension when $n \geq 3$ is prime as it is the commutator/derived subgroup which is always characteristic.

Comment: @Matt B: thanks for your interest. Without even bothering about generality, it would be very helpful just to settle the question I ask ..

Comment: ${\rm SL}(2,Z/nZ)$ is the direct product of the groups  ${\rm SL}(2,Z/qZ)$, where the $q$ are the prime power factors of $n$. And, if $q = p^k$ for prime $p$, then  ${\rm SL}(2,Z/qZ)$ has a normal $p$-subgroup with quotient ${\rm SL}(2,p)$. I think all of the normal subgroups of ${\rm SL}(2,Z/nZ)$ are characteristic.

Comment: @Derek Holt : characteristic in where ..?

Comment: What do you mean? The sentence "all normal subgroups of the group $G$ are characteristic" is clear and unambiguous. BTW, I voted to close this question for lack of context.